# Chef's equivalent of Puppet's defined resource types

Tags: chef-infra, puppet

I'm in the process of converting some puppet manifests to chef. In one of the modules I came across some defined resource types.

As I understand so far what chef offers for this functionality is its Light Weight Resource Providers (LWRP), but aren't those written in plain Ruby?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of alternatives for converting Puppet's custom resources to Chef-like code.

#### LWRPs

As you mentioned, LWRPs (or Lightweight Resource and Providers) are the easiest way to implement a custom Chef extension (I prefer to use the term "extension" because it makes the most sense). Everything in Chef is written in "plain-Ruby", for some subset of Ruby. You can read more about [LWRPs in the docs](http://docs.getchef.com/lwrp.html), but here's a simple example:

```rb
# peanuts/resources/eat.rb
actions :eat, :stomp
default_action :delete

attribute :thing, kind_of: String
attribute :other_thing, kind_of: Fixnum

# peanuts/providers/eat.rb
action :eat do
  # This is Ruby, but in the context of Chef, so you can use recipe snippets:
  template '/foo/bar/blitz.txt'

  # You can also use straight-up Ruby
  File.open('/path', 'wb') { |f| f.write('...') }

  # You can also use "raw" Chef
  remote = Chef::Resource::RemoteFile.new('/path/to/save', run_context)
  remote.source('https://github.com/file/file.tar.gz')
  remote.run_action(:create_if_missing)
end
```

This will expose a custom resource in your recipe named `peanuts_eat`:

```rb
peanuts_eat 'whatever' do
  thing 'string'
  other_thing 1
end
```

### HWRPs

If you are familiar with Ruby, this is the easiest pattern. LWRPs are just a handy DSL around creating real Ruby classes. You can [read more about them here](http://tech.yipit.com/2013/05/09/advanced-chef-writing-heavy-weight-resource-providers-hwrp/), but they look like this:

```rb
class Chef
  class Resource::Peanuts < Resource
    def thing 
      set_or_return(:thing, kind_of: String)
    end

    def other_thing 
      set_or_return(:thing, kind_of: Fixnum)
    end
  end

  class Provider::PeanutsEat < Provider
    def action_eat
      # This is Ruby, but in the context of Chef, so you can use recipe snippets:
      template '/foo/bar/blitz.txt'

      # You can also use straight-up Ruby
      File.open('/path', 'wb') { |f| f.write('...') }

      # You can also use "raw" Chef
      remote = Chef::Resource::RemoteFile.new('/path/to/save', run_context)
      remote.source('https://github.com/file/file.tar.gz')
      remote.run_action(:create_if_missing)
    end
  end
end
```

Usage is the same as the LWRP example

#### LHWRPs

Finally, you can mix the two:

```rb
class Chef
  class Resource::Peanuts < Resource::LWRPBase
    actions :eat, :stomp
    default_action :delete

    attribute :thing, kind_of: String
    attribute :other_thing, kind_of: Fixnum
  end

  class Provider::PeanutsEat < Provider::LWRPBase
    action(:eat) do
      # This is Ruby, but in the context of Chef, so you can use recipe snippets:
      template '/foo/bar/blitz.txt'

      # You can also use straight-up Ruby
      File.open('/path', 'wb') { |f| f.write('...') }

      # You can also use "raw" Chef
      remote = Chef::Resource::RemoteFile.new('/path/to/save', run_context)
      remote.source('https://github.com/file/file.tar.gz')
      remote.run_action(:create_if_missing)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! This solved my problem. I couldn't find any (brief or comprehensive) resource on Chef to Puppet mapping. What I've been doing so far is to do few searches on both constructs and try to figure out the mapping. It would be great if you can provide any resources you know for others too. :)

Comment: Look at the Puppet Jenkins module vs the Chef Jenkins cookbook.